# How do I add a column to a select, from a stored procedure depending on the results from the query?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamicquery

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I need do a search in a table to find if at lest one record matches. After the search is done, a value of true or false is returned from the stored procedure. I was asked to not only return that result of true or false but also add two values from newly added columns. I already have the part of the query that returns true or false (This was previously created). Now I need to create a select that returns these two new values along with the the previously generated value 'T' or 'F' as the result. This value is created using Decode in the following manner: DECODE(COUNT(ColumnId), 0, 'F', 'T') answer. How can I return this true or false value (that doesn't exist in the table) alongside the two values from the table as the SELECT values?

This is for a web service, the database uses Oracle SQL Developer as interface and the client expects the String value along with the two columns value if there is a match. I am going to return the string along with two dummy values is there isn't a match. I have tried selecting the two columns and then selecting that answer varibale with an AS name and it did not work. Selecting the varibale itself did not work either.

```
create or replace procedure
PROCEDURE procedurename
(
Value IN VARCHAR,
BoolValue OUT VARCHAR,
) AS
BEGIN
SELECT DECODE(COUNT(ColumnId), 0, 'F', 'T') answer
INTO Variable
FROM tablename
WHERE (*Conditions*);
END
procedurename

IF answer= 'T' THEN 
            SELECT Val1, Val2, Val3, answer
            FROM tablename
            WHERE col1= 'val1'AND col2 = 'val2';
```

I expect to have a result of (for example):

Val1, Val2, Val3, T

I get:

> "answer" : invalid identifier

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL, and if that query is in a PL/SQL block then it needs to select into something (i.e. three variables), as well as declaring the `answer` variable. If you're trying to run the query as plain SQL then you might be a bit stuck, as you can't call a procedure from SQL. You can call a function, so you could change the procedure to a function, or add a wrapper function, or - from 12c - define a temporary function in a CTE. It isn't quite clear how you need to call this though. Is the procedure query against the same table, and with the same conditions? Is col1/col2 unique?

Comment: I hardcoded it as SELECT 'T' as answer, val1, val2, val3. 
And yes, it is using PL/SQL and it is a store procedure being modified.